# .NET framework change template from empty to MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am running an Umbraco application which I set up using **Empty** template. What I want to do now is to turn it to an **MVC** one.

I've done a lot of work and it's 'dummy' to create a new project from scratch and do everything from the beginning.. Is there any way to turn it to MVC project now?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Umbraco installs mvc so what are you missing?

Comment: @jenson-button-event the problem is that I add a custom controller but it is not hit through ajax

Comment: is that either an Umbraco SurfaceController (mvc) or an UmbracoApiController (Web API 2)? if neither it won't get hit. Since its ajax its the latter you want. Umbraco takes over routing. These are easy things once you know how. Part of Umbraco basics. Web API has a little bit of set up but not much https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

Comment: @jenson-button-event thank you

Comment: this is pertinent: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/routing

Comment: @jenson-button-event The actual problem was on my failure to call the controller properly.. I missed prefix ajax call with '/umbraco/surface'.

Comment: yes been there too